# Engineering Mathematics problem with proving an equation

Tags: derivatives

This is problem 20, further problems in Engineering Mathematics book by K.A.Stroud. It states:

> Show that the equation
>   \begin{equation}
> 4\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 4\mu\frac{dx}{dt} + \mu^2x = 0
> \end{equation}
>   is satisfied by
>   \begin{equation}
> x = (At + B)e^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}}
> \end{equation}
>   where A and B are arbitrary constants.

So i calculated
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} = Ae^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}} + \frac{At^2\mu^2}{4}e^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}} + \frac{Bt\mu^2}{4} e^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{At\mu^2}{4}e^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}} + \frac{At\mu^2}{2}e^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}} + \frac{At^3\mu^4}{16}e^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}} + \frac{B\mu^2}{4}e^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}} + \frac{B\mu^4 t^2}{16}e^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}}
\end{equation}
and then i put everything into the original equation i want to prove and this is what i come up with:
\begin{equation}
(At+B)e^{-\frac{\mu t}{2}} [\mu^3t^2 +4\mu^2t + 8\mu) + 8A(t\mu + 2)
\end{equation}
which isn't equal to 0.

Well, i've completely lost it with this problem, if anyone could help me a bit i would be very, very grateful.

Comment: There seems to be a typo: In the original differential equation, $m$ ought to be $\mu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did something wrong in calculating the derivatives, we have
\begin{align*} \frac{dx}{dt} &= A\exp\left(-\frac{\mu t}2\right) + (At + B)\cdot \left(-\frac\mu 2\right) \exp\left(-\frac{\mu t}2\right) \\ &= 
   A \exp\left(-\frac{\mu t}2\right) - A \frac{\mu t}2  \exp\left(-\frac{\mu t}2\right) - B\frac{\mu}2 \exp\left(-\frac{\mu t}2\right) \end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
  \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} &= -\frac\mu 2 A \exp\left(-\frac{\mu t}2\right)
   - \frac \mu 2 A \exp\left(-\frac{\mu t}2\right) + (At + B)\left(-\frac \mu 2\right)^2 \exp\left(-\frac{\mu t}2\right)  
\end{align*}